# Mongoose populating isn't working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate post with comments. With populating author I didn't have any problems. I tried to populate just comments without author and it didn't work..

Here is the comment model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = require('./user');

commentSchema = new schema({
    comment: String,
    author: { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
})

const Comment = module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

Here is the route:

```
router.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
    Post.findById({ _id: req.params.id })
        .populate('author')
        .populate('comments')
        .exec((err, post) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.json(post);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: What does your `Post` model look like?

Comment: share your Post model schema\

Comment: Could be because of the order of populate? If you want to populate author from Comment, shouldn't you populate comments first?? Just asking

Comment: `
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = require('./user');
const Comment = require('./comment');

postSchema = new schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    author: { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    postImageUrl: String,
    comments: [{ type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]

})

const Post = module.exports = mongoose.model('post', postSchema, 'posts'); `

Comment: I tried to change order, doesn't help..